# Est-ce que "rapport d'activité" prend un "s" à la fin ? et surtout pourquoi ?

Tags: pluriel

Est-ce qu'on dit "un rapport d'activité" ou bien "un rapport d'activités" ? c'est à dire le "s" est ce qu'on l'ajoute ou pas ? mon flair me dit que c'est avec "s" mais je ne suis pas sûr !

Merci de ne pas simplement répondre à la question , mais plutôt me fournir une explication d'ordre général , c-à-d la règle du jeu !

Comment: Voir aussi [ceci](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=rapport+d%27activit%C3%A9&T3.x=0&T3.y=0&id=2914), sur d'autres hésitations avec le nombre du complément du nom. Merci.

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais plutôt qu'un rapport d'activité rend compte de l'activité générale d'une structure, activité qui est bien évidemment "multiple"... et cela donne une idée plus générale.
Si on met un S à activités, cela signifie que l'on rend compte de plusieurs activités, ce qui n'est pas faux en soi, mais dans ce cas on devrait plutôt dire un rapport des activités.
Le cas le plus fréquent est le singulier, donc activité sans "s".

Answer (score 2):

"Un rapport d'activités" est simplement le pluriel de "Un rapport d'activité".

Si vous avez fait plusieurs activités et que vous souhaitez écrire plusieurs activités dans ce rapport, il faut dire "Un rapport d'activités".

Par contre, si vous n'avez fait qu'une seule activité, et que vous souhaitez rédiger qu'une seule activité dans ce rapport, il faudra dire "Un rapport d'activité"

Comment: D'accord pour le reste de la réponse mais le pluriel de « Un rapport d'activité », c'est « Des rapports d'activité ».

Comment: Dans « un rapport d'activité » il s'agit d'un indénombrable.

Answer (score 1):

Je crois qu'il y a même une autre option: « un rapport des activités » quand il y a plusieurs activités facilement dénombrées, mais je préfère « **un rapport d’activité** » (au singulier) quand il s'agit d'un rapport annuel d'une société, bien sûr quand l’activité de la société est carrément indénombrable, mais aussi si ses activités pendant l’année sont à la rigueur dénombrables mais difficilement.  Par contre, pour d'autres rapports d’activité(s), pour une classe a l’école, par exemple, je l’appellerais peut-être plutôt suivant les quantités des activités, mais pour un rapport annuel de société, pour moi ça fait plus sérieux au singulier, comme si la société annonçait au monde qu'elle a tellement d’activités qu'elle n'arrive point à les compter !